# If I install malicious software what may it do?

Tags: security

If I software in a deb file and I do `sudo dpkg -i file.deb` will it execute code from the package and possibly wreck my system?

If I log in as `testuser` and execute the software (simply `thebinary` on the command line) I assume it can read everything testuser can read and can see what processes are running with its arguments (using `ps`). Can it do anything else I might dislike?

Assuming all my personal information is in root or a different user account can malicious software do anything?

Comment: Your question is very broad/vague, but I think the first part is interesting (if `dpkg` could already execute malicious code in `file.deb`).

Answer (score 4):

`sudo dpkg -i file.deb` will happily execute *as root* code from the package `file.deb`. In particular, it'll execute at least the pre- and post-install scripts (which themselves can execute anything, from `rm -Rf --no-preserve-root /` through custom binary code delivered as part of the package.

You should only install packages from trustworthy sources.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the previous answer that correctly states that the installation of packages itself does execute scripts as root during the process, the later execution of the installed software (even by non privileged users) can harm the system and other users files.

During the installation process, the scripts (ran as root) can install suid executable files that when run by ordinary users are elevated to root and consequently are able to cause unlimited damage to the system.  Even worse, this can be done silently and for long periods, like changing system files in a way they will still seem to work as before but under the table steals your data, passwords, banking transactions, etc.  Just google for rootkits, trojan horses, to find some examples of hidden software that do bad under cover).

Do not blindly trust that an ordinary user cannot cause damage to other users or the system.  Even non-intentionally harmful suid system files can have exploits and security flaws that can be explored by non-privileged users to cause harm.

As previously said, you should only install packages from trustworthy sources and also keep your software up to date so that the security flaws and exploits known to date are properly fixed.